# Math.h and FreeRTOS

Tags: c++, xilinx, freertos

I'm having the same problem as described [here](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006mEzwcSAC/mathh-and-freertos?language=en_US) and trying to solve it. The issue is the following:

The following code produces an error:

```
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double x = 3.14;
    double y = fabs(x);
    return 0;
}
```

The message is:  `c:\users\...\.conan\data\xilinx-gcc-arm\9.2.0\...\release\package\e88786b8dcdbe629b8f7989ef7c922fb9791d102\aarch64-xilinx-elf\usr\include\c++\9.2.0\cmath:237:11: error: '::fabs' has not been declared`.

The following code does not produce the error:

```
#include <math.h>
#include "FreeRTOS.h"

int main()
{
    double x = 3.14;
    double y = fabs(x);
    return 0;
}
```

We're using clang tools, the include file order is automatically set (which of course has a workaround, but this is not the solution I'm looking for).

The linked page mentions a solution, which is to include math in the linker library search path, but I'm getting the error while compiling the C++ files. Adding an explicit include search path for the compiler does not help.

Our build environment uses cmake, the compiler is xilinx-gcc-arm 9.2.0, the FreeRTOS version is 10.3.0 (it is the [xilinx port](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/tree/master/ThirdParty/bsp/freertos10_xilinx)).

What causes the problem and how can it be solved (without the above include order hack)?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `FreeRTOS.h`, if there isn't an update available then it seems you already have the best solution by changing the include order

Comment: If it wants you to add the math library to your link command, then add `-lm`  (that's lowercase `-LM`) to your compiler string so your code is linked against the math library. If using a Makefile, you can add it to the `ldflags` variable.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: no, I do not even get to the link step

Comment: Avoid C includes like `math.h`, use `cmath` and `std::` prefixed function names instead (this may or may not solve your problem).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm pretty sure the advice in the linked post is erroneous, this is a compiler error not a linker error